# Grunt build + nginx: unexpected errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx, gruntjs, minify

I understand that there are always risks of going with something nonstandard like `grunt` to deploy projects but I decided to do that anyway. I used Yeoman to scaffold a simple `AngularJS` project and `grunt` to test it. It was all good and I didn't get many `Jslint` errors. I followed all coding standards pretty much.

I then did `grunt build` to build the project (minify et al) and copied the dist folder over to a server. I pointed `nginx` to the `dist` directory and was quite surprised to see many errors in the source files.

The first one is probably an `nginx` configuration issue; I get errors in the console which are;

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

I checked the server configuration but found that in my case, the configuration already had:

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

So no go.

My console is jittered with javascript errors which look like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ui-bootstrap.js:1
```

And I actually see HTML tags having been inserted in ui-bootstrap.js -- either by nginx or by `grunt build`

In any case, this really has me stuck. Can anyone help solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.staticshin.com/minimal-nginx-configuration-for-front-end-development/

Comment: @originof I have and I've repeated their steps one by one. Doesn't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: Anyone? This really is my second bad experience with Grunt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an exact solution to the problem, but from what it looks like, `grunt build` at least in my case skips the following from the `dist/` build;

```
bower_components/
app/template/
app/templates/
bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/ #if you're using bootstrap
```

The solution for me was to manually copy these folders, and then automate it outside of `grunt`.